# LNK2019 LNK2001 errors in visual studio 2017

Tags: opencv, lnk2019, lnk2001

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and building in **x64**. I have 2 libraries linked to my solution file, flann, and **opencv**. I can build the release mode but in debug mode everything is messed up! The problem is with opencv library, and I have double checked the library directories, everything seems to be correct! What am I doing wrong then?!

Here is one of the errors I am getting:

**LNK2001** unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AEAAXXZ)

Comment: In Debug Mode, you link against `opencv_worldxxxd.lib` (pay attention to the d at the end)?

Comment: Yea that part is correct! Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! under solution --> properties --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor  --> Preprocessor Definition: I had WIN32 as one of the definition while building in X64! Removing that fixed my problem!